Alternative proofs of the countable chain condition in forcing
Advance warning: This question is more about history and pedagogy than "hard" mathematics.

I am studying Cohen forcing with the forcing poset $(\operatorname{Fin}(E,2),\supseteq,0)$, and I have seen multiple proofs of the countable chain condition. The proof on the current Wikipedia page goes as follows:

Given an uncountable subfamily $ W \subseteq \operatorname{Fin}(E,2) $, shrink $ W $ to an uncountable subfamily $ W_{0} $ of sets of size $ n $, for some $n < \omega $. If $ p(e_{1}) = b_{1} $ for uncountably many $ p \in W_{0} $, shrink this to an uncountable subfamily $ W_{1} $ and repeat, getting a finite set $ \{ (e_{1},b_{1}),\ldots,(e_{k},b_{k}) \} $ and an uncountable family $ W_{k} $ of incompatible conditions of size $ n - k $ such that every $ e $ is in $ \operatorname{Dom}(p) $ for at most countable many $ p \in W_{k} $. Now, pick an arbitrary $ p \in W_{k} $, and pick from $ W_{k} $ any $ q $ that is not one of the countably many members that have a domain member in common with $ p $. Then $ p \cup \{ (e_{1},b_{1}),\ldots,(e_{k},b_{k}) \} $ and $q \cup \{ (e_{1},b_{1}),\ldots,(e_{k},b_{k}) \} $ are compatible, so $ W $ is not an antichain. In other words, $ \operatorname{Fin}(E,2) $-antichains are countable.

This seems to be a slight rephrase of the one in Cohen's book Set theory and the continuum hypothesis. (Cohen's version directly chooses the largest $k$ instead of describing the iterative procedure.)
However, Cohen's original paper "The independence of the continuum hypothesis, II" seems to have a different proof (Lemma 11) which explicitly enumerates the forcing conditions in $W$. I will describe (my understanding of) it in my own words:

Construct a sequence $P_j$ in stages. In the first stage, choose an arbitrary $P_1 \in W$. In each subsequent stage $k$, let $S_k \subseteq E$ be the union of the (finite) domain of the (finitely many) previously chosen $P_j$. Partition the remaining forcing conditions $P \in W$ according to their values on $S_k$ (i.e., according to $P \restriction_{S_k}$). The possible number of partitions is at most $2^{|S_k|}$. Take one $P$ from each partition to append to the sequence $P_j$.
To prove that $P_j$ contains all forcing conditions in $W$: For any unchosen forcing condition $Q$ at stage $k$, let $P$ be the forcing condition chosen in its partiton instead. Since $W$ is an antichain, $Q$ must be incompatible with $P$ on some element $e \notin S_k$, which will be in $S_{k+1}$. But since $\operatorname{Dom}(Q)$ is finite, we cannot add $e \in \operatorname{Dom}(Q)$ to $S_k$ indefinitely, so at some point $Q$ must be chosen.

Also, the current Wikipedia page says that "It is easy to see that $\operatorname {Bor} (I)$ satisfies the c.c.c. because the measures add up to at most 1". However, it seems to me that the same idea can be easily applied to $\operatorname{Fin}(E,2)$:

For each $n < \omega$, we claim that the set $W_n = \{p \in W \mid |p| = n\}$ is finite — more specifically, $|W_n| \le 2^n$. Otherwise, take a subset $W'_n \subset W_n$ with size $2^n+1$, and let $S$ be the union of the (finite) domain of the (finitely many) $p \in W'_n$. Each $p \in W'_n$ can be extended (strengthened) to exactly $2^{|S|-n}$ forcing conditions $q$ such that $\operatorname{Dom}(q) = S$. Since $W$ is an antichain, the set of $q$ for each $p$ much be disjoint, but then since there are only $2^{|S|}$ possible values of $q$, there can only be $2^n$ distinct $p \in W'_n$, contradicting the assumption $|W'_n| = 2^n+1$.


My questions are:

Why did Cohen change from the second proof to the first one when writing the book? Is there some property (such as ease of extension) that makes the first proof better? (I think that all three proofs rely on the axiom of choice to some extent — at least on a well-ordering of $E$.)
The measure-based proof seems rather natural looking back, now that we know random real forcing. Has it appeared in any paper or textbook?


Incidentally, you may also be interested in Mekler's approach.

I seem to recall that Cohen decided, when writing his book, to frame his arguments more "semantically" than "syntactically," because he felt that doing so would make his work more understandable to "ordinary mathematicians." However, even if this is true, I'm not sure it answers your specific question.
